# Does the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{((x+1)^n-(x-1)^n)}{((x+1)^n+(x-1)^n)}$ exist?

Tags: limits

For positive integer $n$ and real number $x$ ,does the limit exist

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{((x+1)^n-(x-1)^n)}{((x+1)^n+(x-1)^n)}$$?

> if it does what is the value of the limit?

Comment: What limit? The limit as $x\to\infty$? $n\to\infty$? $x\to0$?

Comment: For $x \to 1$ the limit in the numerator and denominator both exist and are nonzero so you just get the quotient of the limits.

Comment: As $x\rightarrow 1$ this isn't even an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{((x+1)^n-(x-1)^n)}{((x+1)^n+(x-1)^n)}=\frac{2^n-0^n}{2^n+0^n}=\frac{2^n}{2^n}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit is not in indeterminate form, so we can simply put in $x = 1$. This gives
$$
\frac{2^n - 0^n}{2^n + 0^n} = 1 \qquad, \forall n \in \Bbb{Z}_+
$$